# Streamlit and asyncio: how to refresh UI

Tags: python-asyncio, streamlit

I run this code below which requests data from an API async and sets `st.session_state` variables, however the UI does not update until I click some random buttons or perform some actions.

How to force a refresh if `st.rerun()` does not work?

```
def run_async_in_thread(awaitable, on_complete, input_):
    def start_loop(loop):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_forever()

    new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    t = threading.Thread(target=start_loop, args=(new_loop,))
    add_script_run_ctx(t)
    t.start()

    async def async_wrapper():
        result = await awaitable # retrieve json from my API
        on_complete(result, input_) # use this json to set session_state vars etc

    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(async_wrapper(), new_loop)
```